# Effects of mushrooms on their hosts

Tags: ecology, mycology, host-pathogen-interaction, mutualism

I learned that mushrooms are normally classified as either *decomposers* or *symbiotes*. I would like to know the differences between the two types and whether they are detrimental or beneficial to their host, often a tree.

Comment: where have you looked for answers so far?

Comment: I have read an article (https://sciencing.com/role-fungi-play-food-chains-13253.html) and their separate wikis.

Comment: They are saprophytes/ saprotrophs / parasitic / symbiont. Of type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably makes sense to classify mushrooms (fungi) in two separate ways:

1. **symbiotic** vs. **free-living**: symbiotic organisms are those that live in *close association* with a host (etymologically sym="with", biosis="life"), free-living organisms don't.  So a [mycorrhizal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza) fungus that lives within or on the surface of a plant root is a symbiote; a fungus that lives in the soil is free-living.
2. **mutualistic** (benefiting from *and* benefiting a host) vs. **parasitic** (benefiting from but harming a host) vs. **saprotrophic** (consuming already-dead material; these are your "decomposers"). (**Commensalism** [benefiting from, but neither hurting nor harming, a host] is  a fourth possibility.) Mycorrhizal fungi are generally mutualistic. Fungi like [chestnut blight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chestnut_blight) or the genus of [phythophthora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytophthora), which includes the organism that causes potato blight, are pathogens; so are the [myco-heterotrophs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myco-heterotrophy). Fungi such as [wood-decay fungi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood-decay_fungus) are saprophytic.

To answer your question, species of fungi that are associated with trees may be either mutualistic (e.g. mycorrhizal fungi) or parasitic (e.g. chestnut blight).

- Parasitic fungi might also be called **pathogenic** (i.e., disease-causing)
- In popular speech, "symbiotic" is synonymous with "mutualistic" (i.e., organisms that benefit each other); in biology, however, it may refer to either a parasitic or a mutualistic organism. An individual symbiotic organism is often called a "symbiont".
- In general, saprotrophs would be free-living (since they don't get their resources from a host, it doesn't really make sense for them to live on a host)
- Individuals of a some fungal species can switch lifestyles/categories depending on their environment: these are called **facultatively** mutualistic/commensal/parasitic, e.g. see Redman et al. 2001.

---

Redman, Regina S., David D. Dunigan, and Rusty J. Rodriguez. “Fungal Symbiosis from Mutualism to Parasitism: Who Controls the Outcome, Host or Invader?” New Phytologist 151, no. 3 (2001): 705–16. https://doi.org/10.1046/j.0028-646x.2001.00210.x.